# sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store an object in sqlite database using python and SQLAlchemy ORM.
Below is my code
**Snippet for storing to sqlite db**

```
command='some command'# a str variable  containing some value
length = len(command) # length of string 
mycommand = Command(command, length, 0, 'nothing') # instantiating object
Session.add(mycommand )
Session.commit()
```

**Snippet for creating session object**

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///commands.db', convert_unicode=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
```

Now when I try to persist a newly crated object to sqlite db using session.add(obj) I get an error :
**sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) memoryview: a bytes-like object is required,**

I have properly created the Command class and mapped its attributes to the corresponding columns in  commands table.
How should I resolve this error?

Comment: If you're using python3, you can make the `command` variable a bytes object by writing `command=b'some command'`

Comment: I tired with str.encode(command) but it does not help.as it wants the object itself in byte format I guess

Comment: Please include the `Command` model itself in your question.

Comment: Thanks you guys ,I figured out where I was going wrong .There was a Blob field in my model and I was trying to insert a string instead of a Binary object into that field.